# Capsule Collider doesn't move smoothly

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have some issues using `CapsuleCollider` and RigidBodyController in a Player `GameObject` in Unity.

Using a `CapsuleCollider` as collider for the player, I noticed that the player doesn't move like a capsule or a sphere (in other words, I want that the movement should be like a rolling ball, with no stuttering), but its movements like more like a box pushed, with stops and starts, that make some little oscillations of the camera.

Any ideas, solutions or tips?

Comment: Can you post any code for us to see? My initial recommendation would be to make sure you are using FixedUpdate.

Comment: As I said, I'm using the default asset RigidBodyFPSControler.cs. So I didn't write the controller code. Looking the code in Visual Studio I can see that all the movement code is in the FixedUpdate() function, and the camera rotating code is in Update().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

realy that is all based on how your moving the object, and the rigidbody2D settings of the object, I think using physics forces would roll your character like a ball or capsule, however just setting a velocity wont.